# WordPress plugin jQuery overriding mine

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I have installed contact form 7 and since doing so my slick slider no longer works. I believe this is because the jQuery that contact form 7 uses is out dated and overriding mine. I'm not using the slick slider plugin I just downloaded the files instead like you would with a none WP site. How can I stop this happening?

Comment: This shouldn't be the case as I have a few websites which use the slick slider and CF7. Are two versions of jQuery definitely loading when you view source?

Comment: @NeilKennedy no it shouldn't be happening I have run them both on sites before. Could it be to do with including my jquery in the head and not the functions file?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest version of WordPress and jQuery has been enqueued correctly you shouldn't have any conflicts.

jQuery should be passed as a dependency in the [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and then you don't have to load it manually.

Here is an example:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slick.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true  );

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery conflict functionality for avoid conflict between jQuery library,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```